# Preserve certain HTML tags when extracting with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, screen-scraping, extract

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="description">Item 1<br>Item 2<br></div>
```

I use BeautifulSoup to get the content in `description` class:

```
descriptionItems = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'}).text.strip()
```

What I get is `Item 1Item 2`

How do I get `Item 1<br>Item 2<br>` instead, i.e. the content between `div` tags, including both `br` tags?

Comment: Does `descriptionItems = container.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'})` alone works ?

Comment: It does, but I get full tag, nothing's stripped: `<div class="description">Item 1<br>Item 2<br></div>`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
container = BeautifulSoup('<div class="description">Item 1<br>Item 2<br></div>', 'lxml')
desc_items = ''.join(str(x) for x in container.find('div', class_='description').contents)
print(desc_items)
# Item 1<br/>Item 2<br/>
```

**Explanation:**

`.contents` gives you a list of all the contents of the tag.

```
['Item 1', <br/>, 'Item 2', <br/>]
```

You can simply join them using `''.join()`. But, the type of tags like `<br/>` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, so `join` will raise a `TypeError` error as it expects all items to be of `str` type. So, you've to convert it to `str` first.

Comment: Works surprisingly well. I didn't even need the first line. Thanks!